# Pygame with Text Input Problems

Tags: python, pygame

Running on python 2.7 with pygame 1.9

My problem was that I needed text input in the little game I was building with pygame. Looking around I spotted [this](https://github.com/ffavela/eztext), which allowed user input.

```
git clone https://github.com/ffavela/eztext.git
```

EzText provided a great way to present the user with a text area, but I needed the text of that text area once the user clicked enter.

With that in mind I modified the bottom of the update function in the eztext file to return the value of the text field.

```
elif event.key == K_RETURN:
    return self.value
    self.value = ""
```

Now, in my main loop in a separate file, I check if the return value is not null, then act upon the result.

```
events = pygame.event.get()
msgvalue = txtbox.update(events)
if msgvalue is not None:
    break # Out of the main loop, so the program closes.
```

Yet, when I do press enter in the text field, nothing happens. It seems almost as if the `update` function is not returning anything. Here is the complete modified function:

```
def update(self, events):
    """ Update the input based on passed events """
    for event in events:
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LSHIFT or event.key == K_RSHIFT: self.shifted = False
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_BACKSPACE: self.value = self.value[:-1]
            elif event.key == K_LSHIFT or event.key == K_RSHIFT: self.shifted = True
            elif event.key == K_SPACE: self.value += ' '
            if not self.shifted:
                if event.key == K_a and 'a' in self.restricted: self.value += 'a'
                elif event.key == K_b and 'b' in self.restricted: self.value += 'b'
                elif event.key == K_c and 'c' in self.restricted: self.value += 'c'
                elif event.key == K_d and 'd' in self.restricted: self.value += 'd'
                elif event.key == K_e and 'e' in self.restricted: self.value += 'e'
                elif event.key == K_f and 'f' in self.restricted: self.value += 'f'
                elif event.key == K_g and 'g' in self.restricted: self.value += 'g'
                elif event.key == K_h and 'h' in self.restricted: self.value += 'h'
                elif event.key == K_i and 'i' in self.restricted: self.value += 'i'
                elif event.key == K_j and 'j' in self.restricted: self.value += 'j'
                elif event.key == K_k and 'k' in self.restricted: self.value += 'k'
                elif event.key == K_l and 'l' in self.restricted: self.value += 'l'
                elif event.key == K_m and 'm' in self.restricted: self.value += 'm'
                elif event.key == K_n and 'n' in self.restricted: self.value += 'n'
                elif event.key == K_o and 'o' in self.restricted: self.value += 'o'
                elif event.key == K_p and 'p' in self.restricted: self.value += 'p'
                elif event.key == K_q and 'q' in self.restricted: self.value += 'q'
                elif event.key == K_r and 'r' in self.restricted: self.value += 'r'
                elif event.key == K_s and 's' in self.restricted: self.value += 's'
                elif event.key == K_t and 't' in self.restricted: self.value += 't'
                elif event.key == K_u and 'u' in self.restricted: self.value += 'u'
                elif event.key == K_v and 'v' in self.restricted: self.value += 'v'
                elif event.key == K_w and 'w' in self.restricted: self.value += 'w'
                elif event.key == K_x and 'x' in self.restricted: self.value += 'x'
                elif event.key == K_y and 'y' in self.restricted: self.value += 'y'
                elif event.key == K_z and 'z' in self.restricted: self.value += 'z'
                elif event.key == K_0 and '0' in self.restricted: self.value += '0'
                elif event.key == K_1 and '1' in self.restricted: self.value += '1'
                elif event.key == K_2 and '2' in self.restricted: self.value += '2'
                elif event.key == K_3 and '3' in self.restricted: self.value += '3'
                elif event.key == K_4 and '4' in self.restricted: self.value += '4'
                elif event.key == K_5 and '5' in self.restricted: self.value += '5'
                elif event.key == K_6 and '6' in self.restricted: self.value += '6'
                elif event.key == K_7 and '7' in self.restricted: self.value += '7'
                elif event.key == K_8 and '8' in self.restricted: self.value += '8'
                elif event.key == K_9 and '9' in self.restricted: self.value += '9'
                elif event.key == K_BACKQUOTE and '`' in self.restricted: self.value += '`'
                elif event.key == K_MINUS and '-' in self.restricted: self.value += '-'
                elif event.key == K_EQUALS and '=' in self.restricted: self.value += '='
                elif event.key == K_LEFTBRACKET and '[' in self.restricted: self.value += '['
                elif event.key == K_RIGHTBRACKET and ']' in self.restricted: self.value += ']'
                elif event.key == K_BACKSLASH and '\\' in self.restricted: self.value += '\\'
                elif event.key == K_SEMICOLON and ';' in self.restricted: self.value += ';'
                elif event.key == K_QUOTE and '\'' in self.restricted: self.value += '\''
                elif event.key == K_COMMA and ',' in self.restricted: self.value += ','
                elif event.key == K_PERIOD and '.' in self.restricted: self.value += '.'
                elif event.key == K_SLASH and '/' in self.restricted: self.value += '/'
            elif self.shifted:
                if event.key == K_a and 'A' in self.restricted: self.value += 'A'
                elif event.key == K_b and 'B' in self.restricted: self.value += 'B'
                elif event.key == K_c and 'C' in self.restricted: self.value += 'C'
                elif event.key == K_d and 'D' in self.restricted: self.value += 'D'
                elif event.key == K_e and 'E' in self.restricted: self.value += 'E'
                elif event.key == K_f and 'F' in self.restricted: self.value += 'F'
                elif event.key == K_g and 'G' in self.restricted: self.value += 'G'
                elif event.key == K_h and 'H' in self.restricted: self.value += 'H'
                elif event.key == K_i and 'I' in self.restricted: self.value += 'I'
                elif event.key == K_j and 'J' in self.restricted: self.value += 'J'
                elif event.key == K_k and 'K' in self.restricted: self.value += 'K'
                elif event.key == K_l and 'L' in self.restricted: self.value += 'L'
                elif event.key == K_m and 'M' in self.restricted: self.value += 'M'
                elif event.key == K_n and 'N' in self.restricted: self.value += 'N'
                elif event.key == K_o and 'O' in self.restricted: self.value += 'O'
                elif event.key == K_p and 'P' in self.restricted: self.value += 'P'
                elif event.key == K_q and 'Q' in self.restricted: self.value += 'Q'
                elif event.key == K_r and 'R' in self.restricted: self.value += 'R'
                elif event.key == K_s and 'S' in self.restricted: self.value += 'S'
                elif event.key == K_t and 'T' in self.restricted: self.value += 'T'
                elif event.key == K_u and 'U' in self.restricted: self.value += 'U'
                elif event.key == K_v and 'V' in self.restricted: self.value += 'V'
                elif event.key == K_w and 'W' in self.restricted: self.value += 'W'
                elif event.key == K_x and 'X' in self.restricted: self.value += 'X'
                elif event.key == K_y and 'Y' in self.restricted: self.value += 'Y'
                elif event.key == K_z and 'Z' in self.restricted: self.value += 'Z'
                elif event.key == K_0 and ')' in self.restricted: self.value += ')'
                elif event.key == K_1 and '!' in self.restricted: self.value += '!'
                elif event.key == K_2 and '@' in self.restricted: self.value += '@'
                elif event.key == K_3 and '#' in self.restricted: self.value += '#'
                elif event.key == K_4 and '$' in self.restricted: self.value += '$'
                elif event.key == K_5 and '%' in self.restricted: self.value += '%'
                elif event.key == K_6 and '^' in self.restricted: self.value += '^'
                elif event.key == K_7 and '&' in self.restricted: self.value += '&'
                elif event.key == K_8 and '*' in self.restricted: self.value += '*'
                elif event.key == K_9 and '(' in self.restricted: self.value += '('
                elif event.key == K_BACKQUOTE and '~' in self.restricted: self.value += '~'
                elif event.key == K_MINUS and '_' in self.restricted: self.value += '_'
                elif event.key == K_EQUALS and '+' in self.restricted: self.value += '+'
                elif event.key == K_LEFTBRACKET and '{' in self.restricted: self.value += '{'
                elif event.key == K_RIGHTBRACKET and '}' in self.restricted: self.value += '}'
                elif event.key == K_BACKSLASH and '|' in self.restricted: self.value += '|'
                elif event.key == K_SEMICOLON and ':' in self.restricted: self.value += ':'
                elif event.key == K_QUOTE and '"' in self.restricted: self.value += '"'
                elif event.key == K_COMMA and '<' in self.restricted: self.value += '<'
                elif event.key == K_PERIOD and '>' in self.restricted: self.value += '>'
                elif event.key == K_SLASH and '?' in self.restricted: self.value += '?'
                elif event.key == K_RETURN: 
                    return self.value
                    self.value = ""
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure update is running? Can you print something out?

Comment: Yup, `update` is running. Typing works

Comment: What do mean by "typing works"

Comment: Typing on the keyboard shows the characters on screen

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding Extext, but how is this confirmation that update() is running?

Comment: Oh, never mind I know what you mean by "print something out". I thought you meant was the text area working? No, I've tried that.

Comment: OK, can you print what self.value is right above where your return it?

Comment: Update is the function that updates the characters on the screen. If it wasn't working, the text field wouldn't show anything when I typed.

Comment: Yes, but something is going wrong with self.value. Let's see what it is right before it is returned to figure out if the problem is in update() or somewhere else

Comment: Trying to print from pygame is slow, plus the main game loop(while 1) is running very speedily. The terminal emulator can't handle printing at that speed because `update()` is called within the main loop

Comment: Let me go to an answer so I can type code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't believe I didn't see this before but if I'm reading your code correctly, the only way update() will detect K_return is if you are holding down shift.

Try moving the applicable object to the part of the conditional that is true if you are not holding down the shift key.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: Eh, I'm not really sure. I guess it's not detecting the `K_RETURN`??

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much. Saved me so much time! I Should have read through the function more in-depth